# How to tell SharePoint 2010 listdata.svc to return JSON via URL?

Tags: json, api, rest, sharepoint-2010

I need the following URL to return JSON:
https://mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Pages

I've tried added the following to the URL (per a blog online but didn't work):
https://mysite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Pages?format=JSON

It always returns XML. Also, I'm not calling the web service via C# or JS code. I'm using a rapid app dev platform that has built-in API consumption. All I need is JSON to be returned (given a URL structure) and I got what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

By default SharePoint 2010 REST service returns results in XML format. To get the results in JSON format, include an `Accept` header set to `application/json;odata=verbose`.

**Example**

```
url: http://site url/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName,
method: GET
Headers:
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I could not find this missing piece in the MS documentation!

Comment: I would like to know one example,how to use the REST call to fetch the listitems/data from a splist thats having calculated columns,list item attachments, multiline text box and number and single line text . i would like to write the code inside a content editor web part. is it possible to download the attachments as well? also can we generate a xml file or csv file with delimiters of the splist items content?  Any links, sources ...

Comment: I noticed that on the documentation for SharePoint 2013 there is a section that outlines a few details about the API, where it mention the `Accept` header option. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#Anchor_0

Comment: One more thing, looks like the documentatin for SharePoint 2010 mentions this as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest